# is it "What are you up today?" or "what are you up to today?"

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-usage

I have always been asked this question but I want to be sure of the correct form. And does the correct form of this question  mean "what are your plans for today?" Or "what will you do today?".

Thank you for any help

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20134/what-does-what-have-you-been-up-to-lately-mean, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2978/what-does-what-are-you-up-to-mean

Comment: There's actually a completely different usage for "What are you up today?"  In financial contexts, particularly that involve fluctuating conditions or profits and losses, being up or down refers to the value of your holdings relative to some previous time.  So if you were inquiring as to how someone was faring in their business venture or investment, and expected that the their holdings were increasing at the moment, you might ask in informal speech, "what are you up today?" or "How much are you up today?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary of American idioms

**be up to something** is the correct sentence.It means: To feel strong enough or knowledgeable enough to accomplish a certain task. Example, **Are you up to**  **preparing dinner for five hundred people?** . A second meaning is: Tendency to do something mischievous.Example, **I'm afraid George is up to one of his old tricks again.** A third meaning is: doing something. Example: **What are you up to right now?** So, to answer your second question, it can mean, "what are your plans/what are you doing today", although it sounds more natural to use it when asking someone what he is doing right now.

Answer (score 1):

*Up to* is common way to ask what are you doing/busy with?

> [up to (adj)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=up%20to) - *Busy or occupied with*

*What are you up today?* does not seem correct to me. The correct usage is **up to**.